# String variable to = a textbox.text

Tags: c#, string, variables

Everywhere I have researched this should work and yet it does not...
I am basically trying to get my variable stores in one class to work on my main form.
I keep getting an error code of

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string` to `Form1.Employee`

My form code

```
Employee FirstName = new Employee();
if (Directions.Text == "Please Enter Employee First Name")
{
    FirstName = Info.Text;
    Directions.Text = "Please Enter Employee Last Name";
}
```

In my second class I have

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName;
}
```

Comment: While technically yes there is more code to this for more variables etc I just wanted to simplify it as much as possible since they all get the exact same error and written the same way

Comment: You included exactly the right amount of code here. The minimal amount of code required makes your question clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first code, `FirstName` is an instance of an `Employee` class. In your

```
FirstName = Info.Text;
```

line, you try to assign `.Text` (which is `string`) property to your class instance which is not possible. That's why compiler says;

> **Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to Employee**

You can assign it's `FirstName` field of your instance to your `Info.Text` value. Like;

```
FirstName.FirstName = Info.Text;
```

Of course would be better if you put a better name on your `Employee` instance.

Comment: Well the Text that it will be equivalent too is what is becoming the name for it so that way I can later show all information added to be displayed for later use.

Answer (score 7):

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
if (Directions.Text == "Please Enter Employee First Name")
{
    employee.FirstName = Info.Text;
    Directions.Text = "Please Enter Employee Last Name";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in following line since FirstName is an instance of Employee.

```
FirstName = Info.Text;
```

It should be

```
FirstName.FirstName = Info.Text;
```

FirstName before dot(.) is the instance of Employee Class and 

FirstName after dot(.) is the field of Employee class